# How do I add javascript tracking code to all magento pages?

Tags: magento

I need to add java script tracking code to all pages of my magento store just before the closing "body" tag. Does anyone know what file I need to put this in? And do I have to modify the JavaScript at all for Magento or just paste it in?

Comment: If your problem has been solved you should accept what you consider is the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question: How do I add javascript to every page

Within the template, typically you load a footer block on every page, so go and find the phtml file here;

```
app/design/frontend/XXX/YYY/template/page/html/footer.phtml
```

Where xxx/yyy is your theme directory.  Add the tracking code here and it will load on every page.

Regarding whether it needs modification - that really depends what you expect to do.  If you need to insert variables such as basket values, customer number (if present) etc, then yes you will need to add those php variables to it, and here is where you could run into trouble.  If you are using caching, then the footer may not be the best place as you could end up with cached variable values in the snippet.   If it dynamically pulls it values for things such as page url, then you'll be ok.

The other problem is that this will load in your checkout pages - so if it calls a js file from an http:// location, your page will fail SSL validation.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding a `layout` file to your module configuration:

```
<config>
    ...
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    ...
</config>
```

Add the `mymodule.xml` file into the `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/` folder and put the following content in there:

```
<layout version="1.0.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template" name="mytracking.block" after="-" template="mynamespace/mymodule/tracking.phtml">
                <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>0</s></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Now you can add your tracking javascript code in this template file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mynamespace/mymodule/tracking.phtml`. It will be printed in all Magento pages.

**EDIT**

I've added a piece of code that disables the cache for your tracking block, thanks to @PixieMedia for letting me know.

Comment: this is much neater, though given the OP's question it could be outside of their skillset.  Also, how about making it not get cached?   Alternatively he could create a faux sidecart block which inherits no cache by default.

Comment: I initially did what Pixie Media advised,  I looked at the java script code and the only reference to http is below...

Comment: pa.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https:' : 'http:') + "//

Comment: @PixieMedia he can disable cache by adding an action on his block, i'll update the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way - via the backend, there is a config section specifically for this need.

`System -> Configuration -> General -> Design Section -> Footer Tab -> Miscellaneous HTML`

It relies on your theme calling the `getAbsoluteFooter()` method in your main template files right before the closing body tag, just be aware of that.

```
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
```